# How to remove everything (including newlines) before a phrase with perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following in a text file (input.txt):

```
/dsdjf48 84f3jh0-=-=-+F_+_m a=
^^^^^^^^^
Random Words
vvvvvvvvv
fkls;[]saf\as-1f-d=fd-s=dsf=-s

Hello, now I will start typing a sentence.
```

I need to remove everything before "Hello, now I will" with perl regex, which I believe supports this.
Here's the command I use:

```
perl -p -e "s/search-term/replace-term/" input.txt
```

When I perform any regex search, it searches line per line. Is there a flag to enable multi-line search?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, using the binary `..` as the [`flip-flop`](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3853051/Perl-and-the-FlipFlop-Operator.htm) operator here.

```
perl -pe '$_ = "" unless /^Hello, now/ .. 1' input.txt
```

Use the `-i` (inline option) to save changes in the input file itself.

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = "" unless /^Hello, now/ .. 1' input.txt
```

Possible to also use `=!!` in this case.

```
perl -pi -e '$_ x=!! (/^Hello, now/ .. 1)' input.txt
```

Comment: `$b` ends with `E0` when second boolean becomes true. Check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: OK, this worked. Just wondering, does the hello, now field still follow regular perl regex?

Comment: Yes, pleace accept and close this question if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -n -e 'print if $_ =~ /^Hello, now I will start typing a sentence\.$/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slurp whole file at once by changing input record separator to `undef`,

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/.*? (?=Hello)//xs' input.txt
```

but better approach would be to go line by line

```
perl -ne '$b = 1 .. /^Hello/; print if $b =~ /^$|E0$/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> perl -i -lne 'BEGIN{$f=0}if(/Hello/){$f=1}if($f){print}' your_file
```